# HAProxy loadbalancing Azure SQL login failed

Tags: azure-sql-database, load-balancing, haproxy, azure-sql-server

I am trying to configure a HAProxy load balancer for an instance of Azure SQL, my config file is as follows;

```
defaults
        mode    tcp
        balance leastconn
        timeout client      30000ms
        timeout server      30000ms
        timeout connect      3000ms
        retries 3
listen sql-db
    bind *:81
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    option log-health-checks
    server DB-1 ********.database.windows.net:1433 check port 1433 inter 1000
```

This configuration file works fine when targeting an instance of SQL Server on an Azure VM. But when targeting Azure SQL the connections are denied due to a logon failure: "Cannot open server "**.**.**.**" requested by the login.  The login failed. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)" I am 100% sure the username/password are correct. They must be getting lost along the way.

Any ideas why this would be?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Were you able to get this to work seamlessly with SSMS?  We are running into all type of oddities with this method, including having to turn SSMS encryption off, state machine context errors when expanding the tree, etc... We have no issues with Datagrip or other clients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out you need to specify the server name in the username when targeting SQL resources.

```
e.g. user@server
```